# How do I return the result of each cross validation prediction

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a task that requires me to analyse a model but I need the output predictions for each cross validation step- and the data that the cross validation used in that step.

Here is my code:

```
results= cross_validate(MLPClassifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5,return_estimator = True)
```

Which did not work. Also,

```
results= cross_val_predict(MLPClassifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

Neither worked, however the second method gave me the a set of predictions that are the shape of y_train (labels). However I expected a smaller value to be returned say 10% the size of y_train.
Also I'm unsure how to obtain the data used for each cross validation step.

Answer (score 0):

How about using one of the [Cross Validation iterators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators)?

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, random_state=0)
datasets = {}  # [(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)]
results = {}

ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
for idx, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(ss.split(X)):
    X_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
    X_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index]

    datasets[f"train_{idx}"] = X_train, y_train
    datasets[f"test_{idx}"] = X_test, y_test

    model = MLPClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
    results[f"accuracy_{idx}"] = model.score(X_test, y_test)

results
```

Output:

```
{'accuracy_0': 0.968,
 'accuracy_1': 0.924,
 'accuracy_2': 0.94,
 'accuracy_3': 0.944,
 'accuracy_4': 0.964}
```

Comment: thank you for this, I need to use my own scoring method which I have been unable to use in the code as "my_scorer". I require to obtain the predictions at each step- is this a possible task??